# Where the conflicting area located?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Based on the following information, when the conflict happens , there  is  conflicting area , however I cannot see that conflicting area in my source code file when the conflict happens, where conflicting area located?
[image]

Comment: Why have you embedded a picture of some text, instead of just pasting the text so it's legible? And, do you have an actual problem, or are you just asking for help understanding a manual?

Comment: I said in the question ,  I cannot see that conflicting area in my source code file when the conflict happens , based on the document it should see that  conflicting area

Comment: So you do have an actual problem! Git should have told you which files it thought had merge conflicts, but it's always possible the conflict was already resolved if you ran a mergetool.